# APC and supporting packages installed but apc not working

Tags: php, apc, apache, yum

I've installed php-pear, php-devel and httpd-devel. All x86.64 version. I've also installed apc (via pecl). I used yum to install the packages. I have added apc.so to php.ini (the correct php.ini too) and restarted httpd. Mind you that I've installed apc from source many times before (but all 32b apache, and php and o/s).

Here is my phpinfo(): http://173.244.212.251/info.php (and for apc info, here http://173.244.212.251/apc.php).

Any help is appreciated.